# Error inserting BLOB into Oracle

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, pdo

I am using this wrapper as the Oracle PDO in PHP is experimental:
https://github.com/yajra/pdo-via-oci8

Here is the PHP code to insert a BLOB that works in MySQL but not yet in Oracle:

```
public function insertPacket($nist) {
  $blob = fopen($nist->getActualFile(), 'rb');
  $sql = "INSERT INTO packets(packet) VALUES(:packet)";
  $query = $this->link->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam(':packet', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
  if(!$query->execute()) {      
     trigger_error(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true), E_USER_ERROR);         
  }
  return $this->link->lastInsertId();
}
```

In oracle I get this exception:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Oci8Exception' with message ' in C:\wamp\www\project\includes\PdoViaOci8\Statement.php on line 156

```
Oci8Exception: Error Code    : 22275
Error Message : ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified
Position      : 12
Statement     : INSERT INTO packets(packet) VALUES(:packet)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a new row in Oracle with a BLOB column, you need to initialize the BLOB column to an empty BLOB before being able to set the bytes.

I am not familiar with the PHP side of things, but basically, your insert statement will have to become something like this:

```
INSERT INTO packets (packet)
VALUES (empty_blob())
RETURNING packet INTO :packet
```

Comment: I tried that but still cannot get the blob in there. It is zero bytes.

Comment: Sorry, but the next step involves more in-depth knowledge of PHP and the specific library you are using, which I don't have.  I only know how to address your specific error from your question (invalid LOB locator), which is that you need to create an empty blob first, so that you can then bind to it.  And then, as a last step, you can push your bytes in.  Sorry that I can't help with that last part.  But hopefully you are now closer to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to allocate the BLOB with the DBMS_LOB_CREATETEMPORARY Procedure.

```
DECLARE
  v_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB_CREATETEMPORARY(v_blob, TRUE);
  v_raw_var := 'abcde';
  DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_blob, v_raw_var);

  INSERT INTO myTab (Key, MyBlobField)
  VALUES (1, v_blob);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

   include '../conexao_oracle.php';

   $db->beginTransaction(); // VERY IMPORTANT !
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
       "INSERT INTO packets (packet) ".
       "VALUES (EMPTY_BLOB()) ".
       "RETURNING packet INTO :packet");
   $stmt->bindParam(':packet', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
   $blob = fopen($nist->getActualFile(), 'rb');
   $stmt->execute();
   $db->commit();
```